# ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point. with scipy least square

Tags: python, scipy

```
import originpro as op
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def circle(ReZ,R1,R2):
    nImZ=(ReZ-R1)*np.sqrt(R2/(ReZ-R1)-1)
    return nImZ

def Fit(func,used_x,used_y,bound,yerror):
    fit_para,fit_cov=curve_fit(func,used_x,used_y,bounds=bound,sigma=yerror,absolute_sigma=True)
    print(fit_para)
    return fit_para

def yerror(ydata, p):
    output=[]
    for i in ydata:
        data=i*p
        output.append(data)
    return output
    
def PrePlot(exp_x,exp_y,fit_x,fit_y):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    fitline=ax.plot(fit_x,fit_y,marker='.',color='blue')
    expline=ax.scatter(exp_x,exp_y,s=20,marker='.',color='red')
    ax.legend(['Experimental','Fitted line'])
    plt.show()

wkslist=range(83,109)    
for wksnum in wkslist:
    wks=op.find_sheet('w','Book'+str(wksnum))
    xdata=wks.to_list(1)
    ydata=wks.to_list(2)
    bound=([3000,1*10**8],[6000,1*10**9])
    error=yerror(ydata, 0.1)
    fitRes=Fit(circle,xdata,ydata,bound,error)
    fit_x=xdata
    fit_y=[circle(x,fitRes[0],fitRes[1]) for x in fit_x]
    PrePlot(xdata,ydata,fit_x,fit_y)
```

I get the error for the second worksheet(wks)

for the function used (circle), the condition is: when ReZ>R1,  R1+R2>=ReZ; when ReZ<R1, R1+R2<=ReZ

The maximum ReZ in the xdata is 1.35e8, the minimum is 4353, which fits that condition with the given boundary.

So I'm really confused here

Comment: Oh I found that the second part of the condition is tricky the boundary doesn't fit lol.But still even I change the bound to bound=([3000,0],[6000,1*10**9]) it is still there

Comment: Try to whittle your code down to the smallest portion of code (1 function?) that represents your problem. Also a reproducible issue has a mock set of data for an example.